# JHipster- Connecting Spring controller to angular js button

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I have an application, where a button must call a spring controller. How do I connect them together?
I have not found any clear information yet.

Comment: It is an API generated by JHipster?

Comment: Can you post the code for the angular button?  I'm thinking this isn't just a simple anchor tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly call your API in `href` in `<a>` tag

API : http://192.168.1.17:8080/product/download/excel

```
<a href="/product/download/excel" > Start Download </a>
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/product/download/excel", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object downloadExcel(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse){
        return productService.downloadExcel(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);
    }
```